# confirm a variable is included in a local?

Tags: foreach, local, stata, capture

I need to run the following loop to generate the squares and cubes of all variables of `local controls` but not the squares and cubes of the variables that are also in the `local controls2`. I guess it is the second line of the code I attach the one I need to know how to do coding.

```
 foreach x of local controls { 
        **capture confirm variable `x' is included in local controls2**
        if !_rc {
        display .
        }
        else {
        gen SQB`x' = `x'^2 
        gen SQD`x' = `x'^3 
        local templist1 = "`x' SQB`x' SQD`x'" 
        local biglist : list biglist | templist1 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `help macrolists` for syntax to get the list wanted before you loop. It's just the kind of thing you are already using within the loop.

```
local wanted : list controls - controls2 
foreach x of local wanted {
```